# How to make product picture full screen in Shopify?

Tags: html, css, image, size, shopify

I have a certain problem with my online shop. Basically, on mobile my product images look too small. I would like them to occupy the entirety of the screen instead (see pic for how it is now).

Any chance someone can help me dig through Shopify assets to fix this?

Thanks!

Here's what it looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/qOF8oSJ

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me which theme you are using and also share the site URL?

Here I am giving you some suggestion.If you only want it to be full screen on the mobile you would have to use the @media screen in your style sheet. It should look something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .image{
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

You may have to add some more CSS to change the size of the image as it may already have a value for the size.

Comment: Hi, the themes is debut and the url is malinkaofficial.com

Comment: Hi @DaniilP. I saw that for mobile device image already using full screen, but if you want to increase the image width more then you can remove the Parent div Left and right Padding and margin.